# Angular 2 and Token authentication

Tags: angular, rest

I have a simple REST API in Java. I test this api via Postman, and everything works. But now I want use this API to learn Angular2. I try login to the application and I have problem, because I don't know how to build request in Angular2. In Postman I do this in this way.

[Postman screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohEKm.png)  
It's my code backend config.

```
package org.mroczek.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT").scopes("read","write","trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource").accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000).secret("secret");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
```

And this is my `autentication.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import {map} from 'rxjs/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        let body = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });

        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/',JSON.stringify({username, password }),{headers})
            .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log(response)
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let user = response.json();
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }
                console.log(user);
                return user;
            });
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }
}
```

When i send request, in backend log I see that page is not found. But I don't have idea what is correct URL.

Comment: Have you read this pages: https://angular.io/guide/http and https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#providing-http-services. They are a great ressources when learning

Comment: I read this pages, but I still don't know how do this.

Comment: Have you written anything so far? If so show us!

Comment: I edit my questions.

Comment: Why do you need to send HTTP requests in tests? Why don't mock them? Like here: https://angular.io/guide/testing#isolated-unit-tests

Comment: Which page is not found? There is no routing in your code which at the first reading seems correct

Comment: Hmm... Gosha_Fighten I think that you wrong understand my intention. I want learn Angular2 and now I try add authentication for my app but I have problem with building request.

Comment: Just don't build requests using pure Angular Http Api ;)

Comment: I reread your code, why don't you use body variable let body = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }); and use JSON.stringify({username, password } ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to learn how it's done, then take a look at [Angular's Http documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data). 
Example usage will probably look this way (not tested, I don't use this api at all):

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  constructor(protected http: Http) {}

  public login() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    let body = {}; // request's body here... (in general password shouldn't be passed as a query parameter, so you will probably like to place it here 
    return http.post('http://localhost:8080/oath/token?grant_type=password&username=user', JSON.stringify(body), {headers});
  }
}
```

Hope it works... Good luck with managing such code for hundreds of endpoints...

If you want a good solution for your application, then I would recommend a library like
[ng2-http](https://github.com/hboylan/ng2-http). It successfully abstracts whole Http layer - no single workaround has been used so far in my project. When using it you don't need to create every request manually, parse response every time etc...
Example usage: for `v0.0.3`

```
// ./providers/rest/localhost.api.ts
@Injectable()
@BaseUrl('http://localhost:8080')
@DefaultHeaders({
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
export class LocalhostApi extends RESTClient {
  @POST('oath/token')
  public postOathToken(
      @Query('grant_type') grantType: string,
      @Query('username') userName: string,
      @Query('password') password: string
      @Body body: PostOathTokenBody
  ) {
    return undefined;
  }
}

// ./providers/rest/types.ts
// for this example let's say you want to send the exact same data as you received
export interface PostOathTokenBody {
  access_token: string;
  token_type: string;
  expires_in: number;
  scope: string;
}

// ./services/some.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  constructor(protected localhostApi: LocalhostApi) {}

  public login(body: PostOathTokenBody) {
    // and that's it, every time you want to use the endpoint, just do:
    return this.localHostApi.postOathToken('username', 'user', 'password', {});
  }
}
```

Moreover I'd define some additional `AbstractApi` class that other Apis will extend, and add: `responseInterceptor(res) { return res.map(r => r.json()); }` so you will get parsed data in every request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I will bring later, when I get home. I am stil try understand "world of angular" but I can't find source of good examples with explanation why I should do that.

Comment: World of Angular is still quite young, so do not be afraid to try new things. You can take a look at [awesome-angular](https://github.com/AngularClass/awesome-angular) - set of many links which may be useful.

Comment: I know how to build simple app in Angular 2 and consume the REST API. But I have problem with authentication. Do you know where I can see working example of user authentication with Java REST API?

Answer (score 0):

So I consume my API using Vue.JS and `axios`

```
login(){
            var params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('grant_type', 'password');
            params.append('username', this.username);
            params.append('password',this.password);
            axios({
                method:'post',
                url:'oauth/token',
                auth:{username:'my-trusted-client',password:'secret'},
                headers: {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"},
                data:params
            }).then(function(response){
                set_cookie("access_token",response.data.access_token);
                document.location.replace("/");
            });
        }
```

Above is code, and this code works correctly. But I still think how to do it correctly in Angular 2.

In Angular 2 I try do this in this way.

```
  login(username, password): Observable<Response> {
const headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'});
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic bXktdHJ1c3RlZC1jbGllbnQ6c2VjcmV0');
headers.append('grant_type', 'password');
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
const body = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});

return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', body, options)
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

But I have this error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/oauth/token. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```